# Proving that a number is divisible by $2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How can I prove that:

$$\frac{1}{2} \left(3 n^2-2\right) \left(3 n^2-1\right) \left(3 n^3-3 n+1\right)\in\mathbb{N}$$

When $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Out of two consecutive integers, one is even.

Comment: @QiZhu I don't see what you mean

Comment: Special case $n=2$ of the dupe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every product of two consecutive integers is even. So $(3n^2 - 2)(3n^2 - 1)$ is even, and the whole product is even (before you divide by 2).

Comment: I don't think so. He asked for proving that a number is divisible by 2, equivalent to proving that this number divided by 2 belongs to $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @JMoravitz I don't think so. That fraction $1/2$, multiplied by an even number, is guaranteed to be an integer.

Comment: we want $\dfrac{1}{2}(3n^2-2)(3n^2-1)(3n^3-n+1)\in \mathbb{N}$, hence proving that $(3n^2-2)(3n^2-1)$ is even is enough

Comment: @JMoravitz Please, reread the original question. Nobody wants you to prove that this is an even number.

Comment: I see it now.  My apologies.  Clearly I need more coffee.  I read the question title "*prove this number is even*" and read it as "*this number*" included the $\frac{1}{2}$ term, not seeing the $\in\Bbb N$ bit.  Poor phrasing of the question in my opinion.